# My Node js program Cannot find a module due to improper path to the folder. How do i fix that?

Tags: node.js, express

I have 3 node js express servers, namely web-app, apiServer and mathsServer, all i different folders on the same level. They are as follows:

-webb-app(folder)
-app.js

-apiServer(folder)
-routes(sub-folder)
**-apiRoutes.js**
-apiController(sub-folder)
**controller.js**

-mathServer(folder)
-controller(sub-folder)
**-mathController.js**
-model(sub-folder)
**-mathModel**

From apiRoutes.js, I do my path as follow (const mathsServer = require(**'.../mathServer/controller/mathController'**);)

but i'm getting an **Error: Cannot find module '.../mathServer/mathModel'**

Answer (score 1):

That's because you typed 3 points instead of 2.

It should be `../mathServer/controller/mathController`

Not          `.../mathServer/controller/mathController`

Comment: Thanks @Aymane Elmadidi. That worked better, but now i have changed to 2 dots like require("../mathServer/model/mathModel");, but getting theError: Cannot find module '../mathServer/model/mathModel'. Check the modified folder structure again.

Comment: i changed it to "../../mathsServer/controller/mathController" and it worked. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'three' dots, instead use 'two' dots. That's how the path is created.

some examples:

```
../../<dir-name>/<file-name>
../<file-name>
../<dir-name>
```